# bxSlider gallery behaves eratically in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome, bxslider

I'm developing a site using the bxSlider gallery. Using default settings, it behaves fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

The HTML is the standard:

```html
<div id="home_title_gallery">
<span class="bxslider_stepback" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_left"></span>
<span class="bxslider_stepforward" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_right"></span>
<div class="bxslider" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1">
<div id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_0">
<img src="/custom/public/images/.slider-01.980.435.0.1.c.png" alt="" title="" data-caption="" data-description="" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_0_2500"></div>
<div id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_1">
<img src="/custom/public/images/.slider-02.980.435.0.1.c.png" alt="" title="/gluten-free-wheat-free-recipes" data-caption="" data-description="" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_1_2501"></div>
<div id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_2">
<img src="/custom/public/images/.slider-03.980.435.0.1.c.png" alt="" title="" data-link="/nutrition-media" data-caption="" data-description="" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_2_2502"></div>
<div id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_3">
<img src="/custom/public/images/.slider-04.980.435.0.1.c.png" alt="PureBred Gluten Free Bread Wheat Free Bread" title="PureBred Gluten Free Wheat Free Bread" data-caption="" data-description="" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_3_2503"></div>
<div id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_4">
<img src="/custom/public/images/.slider-05.980.435.0.1.c.png" alt="" title="" data-caption="" data-description="" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_4_2504"></div>
<div id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_5">
<img src="/custom/public/images/.slider-06.980.435.0.1.c.png" alt="" title="" data-caption="" data-description="" id="bxslider_PagesTitle_1_5_2505"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

(Previously, it was `ul` and `li` instead of nested divs. The behaviour, however, was the same.)

The bxSlider gallery is initiated thus:

```js
app.onload(function(){
    $('.bxslider').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var right_arrow = app.get(id + '_right');
        var left_arrow  = app.get(id + '_left');
        $(this).bxSlider({
            'pager': false,
            'auto': true,
            'nextSelector': right_arrow,
            'prevSelector': left_arrow,
            'nextText': 'Step forward',
            'prevText': 'Step back'
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using our homegrown `app.onload()`, rather than `$(document).ready()`, because I don't actually want the gallery to start sliding till the images are loaded. Here's the function:

```js
var app = {
    get: function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    onload: function(func) {
        // http://www.dustindiaz.com/top-ten-javascript/
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload !== 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            };
        }
    },
    onunload: function(func) {
        // based on above
        var oldonunload = window.onunload;
        if (typeof window.onunload !== 'function') {
            window.onunload = func;
        } else {
            window.onunload = function() {
                if (oldonunload) {
                    oldonunload();
                }
                func();
            };
        }
    }
};
```

This works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it seems to be random. Slightly over half the time, the javascript simply won't run at all, and I'm left with a set of large images all the way down the page and no sliding at all. No relevant error messages show up in the Chrome debugger. Adding `console.log()` in a few places shows that we do get as far as the function `$(this).bxSlider()` (a `console.log()` directly above it fires, anyway), but it doesn't do anything.

How can I work out what's happening here, and how can I fix it?

I used to think that this was something to do with the custom prev and next buttons. It worked when I took them out:

```js
        $(this).bxSlider({
            'pager': false,
            'auto': true,
        });
```

But now I think that was just the luck of the draw (it's behaving erratically, remember). Now it's not working without them either. Well, sometimes it is. More times it isn't.

Comment: What do you mean by " the javascript simply won't run at all" ? app.onload is not triggered you mean?

Comment: We get as far as the bxSlider function, but it doesn't do anything. Have edited question to clarify, @VijetaShetty.

Comment: Hmmm... Not able to figure out what the issue could be. I used your code  $('.bxslider').each(function() {
        $(this).bxSlider({
            'pager': false,
            'auto': true
        });
    }); but called it on $(document).ready(). and it seems to work fine. Shall try with app.onload once.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Ive got the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, @RMSTOKES. Nope. I ended up using a different slider instead.